# Is there a way to record the username that modified a cell to a certain value using a VBA Macro if multiple users open the Excel wbk and change cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with dropdowns in Column A that have various status values like "In Progress", "Complete", "N/A", and the like.

Goal: When any dropdown in Column A is changed to "Complete", I would like to record the username of the person that made the change and have that value persist even if another user opens the spreadsheet and changes other cells. For example, if Sally changes A1 to Complete, then Becky opens the workbook and changes A2 to Complete, B1 and B2 should read "Sally" and "Becky", respectively.

I have tried several iterations of the code below and the problem I keep running into is that when a new user opens the workbook and changes any of the dropdowns, all other username references in Column B switch to the new user.

VBA Macro:

```
Public Function LastModifiedByUser(ByVal Target as Range)

     If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Target) Is Nothing Then
          LastModifiedByUser = Application.UserName
     End If

End Function
```

The formulas in Column B look like:

```
=IF(A1="Complete",LastModifiedByUser(A1),"")
```

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if anything is unclear or more info is needed. Thank you!

Comment: You need to use an Event, specifically Worksheet_Change event.  Formula are live and will change when calculated.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner. I will start trying things with a Worksheet_Change event and see if I can get there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need, if I got well your question, if not try to clarify and I will adapt the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If (Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing) Then
 Range("B1").Value2 = Application.UserName
 End If
 
 If (Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing) Then
 Range("B2").Value2 = Application.UserName
 End If
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to JustGreat an alternative version. EnableEvents = False ist needed due to the macro triggering itself by setting a value to the sheet. ThisWorkbook.Save can alternativly be set as a Workbook_BeforeClose Event and may be much more secure.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    With Application
    
        .EnableEvents = False
        
         If Not .Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = .UserName
         End If
        
        .EnableEvents = True
        
    End With
 
 ThisWorkbook.Save
 
End Sub
```